# In what scenario is having separate login pages for users and administrators better?

Tags: php, security, admin, user-accounts

I am creating my first web app from scratch using PHP. I won't be using a framework.
My proposed file structure looks something like:

```
index.php
/images
/css
/js
/classes
/includes
/views
/modules (blog, forum, etc.)
```

I'm also considering including /admin maybe.

What concrete decisions/considerations do I need to make before taking an approach, i.e. choosing between {mywebapp}.com/login (for both users and admin) or {mywebapp}.com/admin (for just the administrators)? And why?

Comment: Completely up to you! If the admin area is the same as the user area but with more features, I usually give them the same login. If the admin area is it's own separate area, I usually do the /admin bit.

Comment: It would be a bit of a mess in the code but I recommend that you keep the same page since you are new to php and if your app is simple enough. You could separate the pages but you will need to use either php session or cookies which is not very ideal.

Comment: Mhh why are "session or cookies not very ideal"? I haven' t seen an app/framework which doesn' t make use of at least on of it...

Comment: @zaw, How would you propose keeping session information then?  There is certainly nothing wrong with sessions/cookies.

Comment: Well now, I'm pretty stumped as to editing this question such as to not solicit opinions. Somebody please help! I would like to say thanks for all the helpful suggestions, they'll go a long way in helping me with my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/public
   /images
   /css
   /js
   index.php
/classes
/includes
/views
/modules (blog, forum, etc.)
```

Your doc_root would by site-path/public.

An admin should be a user with extra privileges. As long as your login process is secure, there is no reason for a separate admin login.

Comment: +1 for moving the code out of the doc root.

Answer (score 2):

This is a UI(user interface) question. I cant find any clear programmatic advantage for either of them, and have seen frameworks implement both of them.

In my opinion, you should have a special login page for the admin if you have a distinct and  separate 'back office' or a specialized admin panel. If the admin is like any other user, but with extra privileges, using a combined login seems like the way to go.

Comment: That's exactly what I was concerned about - the admin panel becoming so specialized and different that keeping a combined interface would become cumbersome somewhere down the line.